# Do we have short circuit logical operators in C shell script?

Tags: scripting, shell, csh, tcsh, short-circuiting

I thought C shell script will behave like C and use short circuit evaluation for logical operators.

```
if ((! -e $cache ) || ("`find $monitor -newer $cache`" != "")) then
...
endif
```

But in the if statement, even if the first condition is true, the second is checked giving me errors.

Do we have a short circuit logical OR in C shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `&&`and `||` are short-circut. Consider something like this:

```
$ false && echo foo
$ true || echo foo
```

In both cases, foo won't be put out.

But, AFAIK you cannot use this kind of string comparison like this, even if short-circuit, csh will still syntax-check the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `&&` and `||` are short-circuit operators in tcsh (just as they are in C).  And there are two distinct forms, one that works on commands (as in `false && echo foo`), and one that works on expression (as in `if (-e $file1 && -e $file2)`).

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, except that csh and tcsh are notorious for ill-defined syntax.  A bit of experimentation shows that saving the output of `find` in a variable avoids the error:

```
set s = "`find $monitor -newer $cache`"
if ((! -e $cache) || ("$s" != "")) then
    echo ok
endif
```

(Note that the extra parentheses aren't really necessary, but they don't hurt anything.)

But more improvement is possible.  Storing the entire output of the find command in a variable isn't really necessary.  Instead, you can invoke find and use its returned status to tell you whether it found anything:

I just tried this:

```
if (! -e $cache || { find $monitor -newer $cache >& /dev/null } ) then
    echo ok
endif
```

and it worked -- except that the `>& /dev/null` redirection seems to be ignored within the braces.

Instead, you can execute the "find" command separately, and then examine the resulting $status.  Which means that you lose the benefit of the short-circuit `||` operator; you'll have to resort to nested `if` statements and/or temporary variables.

Perhaps the real lesson is this: I've been using csh and tcsh for more years than I care to admit, and the only way I was able to figure out a lot of this stuff was by trial and error.  You *can* do this using tcsh or csh, but you're probably better of using a different scripting language.  For example, in Bourne shell, this is fairly straightforward:

```
if [ ! -e $cache ] || find $monitor -newer $cache >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    ...
fi
```