# Check if a variable is undefined or empty in single if-condition in csh

Tags: if-statement, csh

The variable existence and empty values can be checked in separate if-conditions in csh.

```
if (! $?theVar) then
```

or

```
if ($theVar == "") then
```

I would like to check these conditions in a single condition. Tried something like

```
if ((! $?theVar) || ($theVar == "")) then
```

But it is not working as expected. It seems to be simple and I couldn't find a similar question. Please feel free to point it, if the question already exists.

Note: Can't change the shell. Need solution in csh only.

Comment: This is difficult because of csh's ad-hoc parser which doesn't really follow normal rules as in other language, it's *extremely* sensitive to spaces (`if (! $?theVar || $theVar == "" )` kinda works), and it also doesn't follow normal evaluation (it won't work if `theVar` is undefined because the part after the `||` also gets evaluated). I'd just keep the two `if`s; there's no way to get around writing ugly code if you're working with csh :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even if "||" is considered to be a short-circuit operator, CSH will still syntax-check the whole thing. hence causing you the trouble.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694163/do-we-have-short-circuit-logical-operators-in-c-shell-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640093/how-can-i-check-if-a-variable-is-empty-or-not-in-tcsh-shell)

Try this **if ((! $?theVar) && set theVar = "") || ($theVar == "")) then**